# Move user-profile under Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have updated Windows 7 to Windows 10.
I used the built-in Administrator-account under Windows 10 to work with my pc.
But under Windows 10, Edge and some other apps don't work with the buit-in admin-account.

So I wanted to move the whole user-profile - preferredly including the registry - to a new account.

Does anyone here have a recipe how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't something that's really done. The problem you face is that each profile has a unique identifier (a SID.) I'm not sure if that sid is stored in the ntuser.dat file (The user registry hidden in your user account.)

I would suggest using the tools Microsoft and other software providers have made available for migration. For web browsers you can transfer your bookmarks by exporting them. Documents you can copy over to the new user. You could potentially link a Microsoft account to the built in admin and your new account and have that sync a lot of your settings over.

This does involve some initial set up time, but then your not having to worry about a bodge job going wrong. Things like recent documents in word/powerpoint etc will not come over, but that list will quickly repopulate. I have just done 2 windows 10 reinstall for family members and within a couple of hours it was business as normal for them.